# Handling Ratio of Gamma Functions in MLE for Dirichlet-Multinomial Distribution

Tags: gamma-function, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to perform Maximum-Likelihood estimation for the $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ parameters of the Dirichlet-Multinomial function for a single observation, taken from [this paper](https://tminka.github.io/papers/dirichlet/minka-dirichlet.pdf):

$$
p(\boldsymbol{x}|\boldsymbol{\alpha})=\frac{\Gamma(\sum_{k}\alpha_k)}{\Gamma(\sum_kn_k+\alpha_k)}\prod_k\frac{\Gamma(n_k+\alpha_k)}{\Gamma(\alpha_k)}
$$

To do this, I re-implemented the function in `Python` and tried to use some numerical optimization approaches for it, like `scipy.optimize.minimize`. However, if any $n_k$ gets reasonably large (>175), the Gamma function values overflow. This is not helped by e.g. log transformations.

Thus, I was wondering if there is any algebraic procedure to re-write the ratio of $\Gamma$ into an expression that does not get this large.

Alternatively, I am also happy for ways to handle the overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to revolve round how to evaluate
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Gamma(n_1 + \alpha_1)\cdots\Gamma(n_K + \alpha_K)}{\Gamma(n_1 + \alpha_1 + \cdots + n_K + \alpha_K)}. 
\end{equation}
You might want to work with the logarithm of this quantity instead. If you're doing MLE or MAP estimation this will come about naturally, a [nice illustration here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089812219290016B).

ADDED

Using a current version of `scipy.special.loggamma` I'm able to get $\log\Gamma(x)$ for $x = 10^{305}$.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion of the ```scipy.special.loggamma``` function. I only tried ```np.log(Gamma(n_k))``` but that did not solve the problem of overflow because the inner function still needs to be evaluated. Still would be interested in an algebraic solution for re-writing this though (but there might be none available..)